# Jquery issues related to unload function in body

Tags: jquery

When i try to get out of the page it should ask confirm message if i click ok it redirected to some other page if i click "Cancel" it shold stay on the same page Who?

Comment: You mentioned issues. What are the issues you are facing? What is the code that you have?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `onbeforeunload` like this

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
        return "There are unsaved changes to your survey";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant redirect to some other page when clicking OK, the browser won't provide such an option.All you can do is show a warning message before closing the tab/window. Modern browsers won't even allow to show custom messages too in that window.

Comment: What makes you think "Modern browsers won't even allow to show custom messages too in that window"? I have yet to see such a case.

Comment: @JanDvorak https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=588292  Firefox versions after 4.0 and chrome/safari too won't show this message. I have tried this on my own

Comment: Any reason behind this decision? I can't see how is displaying a site-supplied text conisdered a security issue.

Comment: not sure, but virus sites do reverse psychology like: "Click cancel to not install the virus" OR "CLOSING THE WINDOW WILL AFFECT YOUR CREDIT RATINGS"

Comment: I still oppose the decision if potential phishing attempts are the only security threat here.